# Web API, AutoMapper and DTO/Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dto

I keep my model in a Model assembly and the DTO classes in a DTO assembly. Both are referenced in the WebAPI project and mappings are created there. The WPF client just references the DTO assembly.

My entities have an 'Id' identity property and I set the access modifier to internal so that the id is only set in the model assembly (backed by EF6). Even the Id in the DTO is set to internal.

The problem is that when the DTO reaches the client, the Id is 0. Do I need to set the accessibility to public? What if the client changes the id and saves the entity? This will cause problems.

Is there another alternative?

Comment: You can make only getter public... BTW, I don't see problem if somebody changes id in dto, when you will saving or updating - it will be ANOTHER entity. And you will check business rules and permissions of that ANOTHER entity.

Comment: Maybe I explained a little unclear. For example, you have User{Id = 1, Name = "Ivan"} and User{Id=2, Name="Piotr"}. Somebody changed Id of first entity to 2 and submitted to update. Your business layer gets from DB entity with ID = 2, and try's change name to Ivan. And now it's your business rules to allow or deny this change: permissions and etc. Never trust user input, trust only server side - check in server side everything what user submits.

Comment: And just one moment, WPF and WebApi shares same class, but they dont't share instance of that class. WebApi gets serialized version of the object and it's up to you to decide how to attach it to real data. DTO - is simple envelope.

Comment: Is there a way to add an attribute to the Id property so that the client can't modify it?

Comment: What if client doesn't use WPF client at all? And will call your web api directly?

Comment: The Id property of both the model and dto must be readonly to the client. However, currently I can't do this because the model and to are separate projects. The Id should only be set by the service when loading an existing entity or saving a new entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Id` field shouldn't be read only, both in the server and in the client.

They have to be set both in the server by EF, and in the client by the serializer, so you do not want to make it inaccessible.
If you don't want the user to mess with it, I'd say just mark it with the [Obsolete] attribute or some other means of warning user, but you should keep it visible and editable.